# Python loop through a range and print into a csv for different columns with different ranges

Tags: python-3.x

I have three different columns that I need to print them into a CSV which each column have a different range for each column using Python

e.g column 1 - range: 0 to 5000

- column 2 - range: 450123 to 565123
- column 3 - range: 125000 to 130000

Would like to print these columns into a CSV something like this

```
column1, column2 , column3 
0,450123,125000
1,450124,125001
......
......
5000,565123,130000
```

```
import csv

header = ['column1']
with open('test.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n', )
    writer.writerow(i for i in header)
    for j in range(1, 500001):
        row = ["martec" + str(j)]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I managed to get it for one column but would to print multiple columns

Comment: sorry the code i attached is not correct  ```import csv

header = ['column']
with open('test.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n', )
    writer.writerow(i for i in header)
    for j in range(1, 500001):
        row = [j]
        writer.writerow(row)'''

Comment: Column 2 has a different number of rows than the other two, if I'm understanding. Is that right? So for the expected output, You wouldn't have '565123' on the same row as 5000 and 130000, you'd have something like 455123, and then you'd have another 11k rows.

Answer (score 0):

As scotscotmcc pointed out, the output won't be exactly as you want it.  There are unequal ranges in the three columns.  But assuming the columns should all have the same amount of numbers in them then something like the following should work.  You just need to add all three columns to the list (row) to be written to the csv.

```
header = ['column1','column2','column3']
max = 5000
with open('test.csv','w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(header)
    for i in range(0,max):
        row = [ i, 450123+i, 125000+i ]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Output would be something like

```
column1,column2,column3
0,450123,125000
1,450124,125001
2,450125,125002
3,450126,125003
4,450127,125004
5,450128,125005
6,450129,125006
7,450130,125007
8,450131,125008
```